# Unfamiliar form of coupled ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've recently come across a system of coupled ODE's:

$$x_2''-x_1''=A-Bx_2$$
$$x_1''-x_2''=C-Dx_1$$

where $x_1, x_2$ are functions of only $t$.

I am sort of stumped. Just by adding these equations together, one gets:

$0 = A+C-Bx_2-Dx_1$

which appears to imply, at least to me, that any function will work given that,

$x_1 = \frac{A+C-Bx_2}{D}$

However, this is not true when I enter a possible pair of functions,

$x_1 = \frac{A+C-Bt^2}{D}$

$x_2 = t^2$

This clearly doesn't work as $x_1''$ and $x_2''$ both wouldn't have dependence on $t$ which implies my assumption that any equations would work as long as they constrained to the $0 = A+C-Bx_2-Dx_1$ equation is false. How do I go about solving this coupled ODE?

Answer (score 4):

"*which implies my assumption ... is false*" Yes, you can't put any function that satisfies $x_1 = \frac{A+C-Bx_2}{D}$ because it is just one condition, whereas the original system had two equations. So while all solutions of the original system must obey your new equation, there is one more condition they need to also satisfy. It's the difference between 'necessary' and 'sufficient' conditions.

But back to the problem, it is still a step. Use your new equation to substitute for $x_1$ in terms of $x_2$ back in one of the ODEs, you'll get a second-order ODE in just one variable, and try solving from there.

Answer (score 2):

Calling $\eta = x_2-x_1$ we have

$$
\cases{
\ddot\eta = A-B x_2\\
-\ddot\eta = C-D x_1
}
$$

subtracting after multiplying the first ode by $D$ and the second by $B$ we have

$$
(D+B)\ddot\eta + DB\eta = DA-BC
$$

Solving this ode for $\eta$ we have finally

$$
\cases{
\eta = x_2-x_1\\
Bx_2+Dx_1 = A+C
}
$$